# Longtable with 34 columns

Tags: longtable

I have some very basic LaTeX knowledge, so I am hoping to find a solution here in the TeX community and I am hoping someone will be kind enough to provide help.

I have a data frame of 34 columns and 25 rows. Using the data I need to produce a table in landscape layout. This where I got so far, as you can see I had to scale down the table in order to have it on just one page. I would like to split it at a certain column and reproduce the first column with the State's name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
  \begin{center}
  \begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90, width=\columnwidth-80pt }
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
  & AIF & BLOS & C-UAS & CBRN SaaS & Co-basing & CRRT MACS & Cyber Threats & DIVEPACK & DMDRCP & EHAAP & EMC & EOF & ESSOR & EU IntSchool & EU TCC & EU TEC & EU TIGER Mark & EU TMCC & EU-SSA-N & EUFOR Crisis & EURAS & Eurodrone & GEMSCE & GMSCE & H3 Training & HARMSPRO & IFS & JISR & MAS MCM & Military Mobility & NLHSuOp & SOF C2CP & Strategic C2 & UGS & Upgrade MS \\ 
  \hline
  Austria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Belgium &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Bulgaria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Croatia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Cyprus &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Czech Republic &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Estonia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Finland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  France &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Germany &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Greece &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Hungary &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Ireland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Italy &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Latvia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Lithuania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Luxembourg &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Netherlands &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Poland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Portugal &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Romania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovakia &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovenia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Spain &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
    % add a caption if you want
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without having looked at the compiled result: Would it perhaps fit, if you rotate the text in the top row by 90 degrees?

Comment: Big tables are very boring and they are not 
an easily digestible piece of information for us humans.
A tip, found somewhere some time ago:
do not use a table, if it does not fit a one portrait page.
So, a very subjective comment:
split it into several smaller parts.

Comment: Actually, I like the question: With `longtable` you can repeat the table’s header on different pages. Is there an equivalent for horizontally stretched tables? One could still use a rotated `longtable`, I guess, where you take the first column as repeatable table header …

Comment: Thank you guys, all your suggestions were good so I've tried them all. Indeed, longtable package was doing well. I've split the table in two parts and now is more readable. Thank you again! This community is really helping

Answer (score 1):

With a little work, you can fit it on one page (portrait).

I would replace all the zeros with blanks and the ones with something more distinctive.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newcommand*{\Rtext}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=Bl]{90}{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
  \begin{center}
  %\begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90, width=\columnwidth-80pt }
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
  & \Rtext{AIF} & \Rtext{BLOS} & \Rtext{C-UAS} & \Rtext{CBRN SaaS} & \Rtext{Co-basing} & \Rtext{CRRT MACS} & \Rtext{Cyber Threats} & \Rtext{DIVEPACK} & \Rtext{DMDRCP} & \Rtext{EHAAP} & \Rtext{EMC} & \Rtext{EOF} & \Rtext{ESSOR} & \Rtext{EU IntSchool} & \Rtext{EU TCC} & \Rtext{EU TEC} & \Rtext{EU TIGER Mark} & \Rtext{EU TMCC} & \Rtext{EU-SSA-N} & \Rtext{EUFOR Crisis} & \Rtext{EURAS} & \Rtext{Eurodrone} & \Rtext{GEMSCE} & \Rtext{GMSCE} & \Rtext{H3 Training} & \Rtext{HARMSPRO} & \Rtext{IFS} & \Rtext{JISR} & \Rtext{MAS MCM} & \Rtext{Military Mobility} & \Rtext{NLHSuOp} & \Rtext{SOF C2CP} & \Rtext{Strategic C2} & \Rtext{UGS} & \Rtext{Upgrade MS} \\ 
  \hline
  Austria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Belgium &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Bulgaria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Croatia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Cyprus &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Czech Republic &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Estonia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Finland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  France &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Germany &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Greece &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Hungary &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Ireland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Italy &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Latvia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Lithuania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Luxembourg &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Netherlands &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Poland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Portugal &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Romania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovakia &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovenia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Spain &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  %\end{adjustbox}
    % add a caption if you want
  \end{center}
%\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Further experiments showed how to use the whole width.  Note that `\extracolsep` does not affect the space at the far left and right edges.  (It looks better without showframe.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newcommand*{\Rtext}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=Bl]{90}{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
  \begin{center}
  %\begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90, width=\columnwidth-80pt }
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{0pt plus 1fil}}rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
  & \Rtext{AIF} & \Rtext{BLOS} & \Rtext{C-UAS} & \Rtext{CBRN SaaS} & \Rtext{Co-basing} & \Rtext{CRRT MACS} & \Rtext{Cyber Threats} & \Rtext{DIVEPACK} & \Rtext{DMDRCP} & \Rtext{EHAAP} & \Rtext{EMC} & \Rtext{EOF} & \Rtext{ESSOR} & \Rtext{EU IntSchool} & \Rtext{EU TCC} & \Rtext{EU TEC} & \Rtext{EU TIGER Mark} & \Rtext{EU TMCC} & \Rtext{EU-SSA-N} & \Rtext{EUFOR Crisis} & \Rtext{EURAS} & \Rtext{Eurodrone} & \Rtext{GEMSCE} & \Rtext{GMSCE} & \Rtext{H3 Training} & \Rtext{HARMSPRO} & \Rtext{IFS} & \Rtext{JISR} & \Rtext{MAS MCM} & \Rtext{Military Mobility} & \Rtext{NLHSuOp} & \Rtext{SOF C2CP} & \Rtext{Strategic C2} & \Rtext{UGS} & \Rtext{Upgrade MS} \\ 
  \hline
  Austria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Belgium &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Bulgaria &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Croatia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Cyprus &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Czech Republic &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Estonia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Finland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  France &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Germany &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Greece &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Hungary &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Ireland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Italy &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 \\ 
  Latvia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Lithuania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Luxembourg &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Netherlands &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Poland &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  Portugal &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Romania &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovakia &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Slovenia &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  Spain &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular*}
  %\end{adjustbox}
    % add a caption if you want
  \end{center}
%\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you John, your solution is what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help as well as others contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is really huge ... I would rotate it with use of `sidewaystable` defined in the `rotating` package. Also column headers had to be rotated. For this I would use `\rothead` command defined in the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\newcommand\RH[1]{\rothead{#1}}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont EU TIGER Mark}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r@{\ }|*{35}{r} }
    \hline
  & \RH{AIF}            & \RH{BLOS}                 & \RH{C-UAS}            & \RH{CBRN SaaS}
  & \RH{Co-basing}      & \RH{CRRT MACS}            & \RH{Cyber Threats}    & \RH{DIVEPACK}
  & \RH{DMDRCP}         & \RH{EHAAP}                & \RH{EMC}              & \RH{EOF}
  & \RH{ESSOR}          & \RH{EU IntSchool}         & \RH{EU TCC}           & \RH{EU TEC}
  & \RH{EU TIGER Mark}  & \RH{EU TMCC}              & \RH{EU-SSA-N}         & \RH{EUFOR Crisis}
  & \RH{EURAS}          & \RH{Eurodrone}            & \RH{GEMSCE}           & \RH{GMSCE}
  & \RH{H3 Training}    & \RH{HARMSPRO}             & \RH{IFS}              & \RH{JISR}
  & \RH{MAS MCM}        & \RH{Military Mobility}    & \RH{NLHSuOp}          & \RH{SOF C2CP} 
  & \RH{Strategic C2}   & \RH{UGS}                  & \RH{Upgrade MS} \\
  \hline
Austria
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Belgium
    &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Bulgaria
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
Croatia
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
Cyprus
    &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
Czech Republic
    &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Estonia
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Finland
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
France
    &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\
Germany
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\
Greece
    &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
Hungary
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Ireland
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
Italy
    &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 \\
Latvia
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Lithuania
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Luxembourg
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Netherlands
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Poland
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 \\
Portugal
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 \\
Romania
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Slovakia
    &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Slovenia
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
Spain
    &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]